# Reading text file in order

Tags: python, text, mouse-position

There's no errors, but I'm having trouble getting it to read from the beginning. I want it to start from the beginning to the end then stop. The text file is my mouse positions so it looks like this

### Text File

```
(1768, 170)
(1768, 170)
(1768, 170)
(1768, 170)
(1768, 170)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1770, 168)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1771, 163)
(1772, 160)
(1772, 160)
(1772, 160)
(1772, 160)
(1772, 160)
(1772, 160)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1774, 158)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1775, 155)
(1776, 152)
```

### Code

```
import os
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

A = 1
width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
middle = ((width / 2), (height / 2))
TL1 = ((width / 2) / 2, (height / 2) / 2)
TR2 = (width / 2) * 1.5, (height / 2) / 2
BL3 = ((width / 2) / 2), ((height / 2) * 2) / 1.5
BR4 = (width / 2) * 1.5, ((height / 2) * 2) / 1.5

mouse = Controller()
mousePos = mouse.position
run = True
while run:
    # file1 = open("fp.txt")
    points = set()
    with open("fp.txt", "r") as f:
        # each line separately
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            # strip \n  & strip ( and ) & split at ,

            pointstring = line.strip().strip("()").split(",")
            # guard against empty/non well formed lines
            if pointstring and len(pointstring) == 2:
                points.add(tuple(map(float, pointstring)))
            else:
                print(f"Error in line {idx}: '{line}'")
    mousePos = pointstring
    if mousePos == pointstring:

        # mouse.position = file1.read().splitlines()

        mouse.position = pointstring
        print(pointstring)
```

Im only getting the last cord. for example (1776, 152)--> from text file.
my goal here is trying to be able to mimic my mouse positions. im trying to read a line from the text like (170, 304) then use it and on to the next, line by line.

Comment: _Im only getting the last cord_ What do you mean exactly?  Is there a variable that you're expecting to have all the coordinates, but it only has one?

Comment: You're saving each position in `points`, but then you never use that variable again...

Comment: im trying to read a line from the text like (170, 304) then use it and on to the next.

Comment: You're saving each line of text in `points`, but then as far as I can see you never actually use that variable for anything.  Once the loop is over you use `pointstring`, which is of course the very last line that was read from the file.

Comment: when I do use points I get this error
   pos = int(pos[0]), int(pos[1])
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That uses `pos`, not `points`.  What is `pos`?

Comment: pos are the mouse positions its suppose to be in this format mouse.position = pos, pos

Comment: `pos` is not mentioned anywhere in the code.  Very hard to answer when you keep throwing in new variables...

Comment: its imported from pynput.mouse

Comment: my bad i didnt specify its in mouse.position = points when I changed it from pointstring to points